# How can I avoid this markup is filtered out from my block?

Tags: wysiwyg, input-formats

I generated a widget on pinterest. The result is the following:

```
<a data-pin-do="embedPin" href="http://nl.pinterest.com/pin/1438168111370/"></a>
<!-- Please call pinit.js only once per page -->
<script type="text/javascript" async defer src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

`pinit.js` is included in the theme and is available in the page.

I added a block with the following code.

```
<a data-pin-do="embedPin" href="http://nl.pinterest.com/pin/1438168111370/"></a>
```

When I saved the block (I used CKEditor), it cleaned. Actually, I don't know if it is cleaned by **CKEditor** or the **full HTML** filter.

How can I find out which of those is cleaned out the markup?

- If it's due to **CKEditor**, how can I solve it? The `advanced content filter` is disabled.
- If it's due to **full HTML** filter, how can I configure it so that only this non compliant syntax is allowed?

**NOTE:** In the **full HTML** filter, the checkbox `Correct faulty` and chopped off `HTML` is NOT checked.

Comment: In the Full HTML input format do you have "Limit allowed HTML tags" or any other HTML limiting filters? It is possible to have them enabled even though it is called Full HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same issue with CKEditor removing classes in the past, Full HTML is not the issue.

Add the below code to the end of your CKEditors config.js file, which is found within the CKEditor library code.

```
CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
```

You might find that the file is called ckeditor.config.js and that this is the file that needs to be changed rather than the default config.js. This file can be found in the root of the CKEditor module.

Comment: Perfect solution !!!